# Adapt to Corrplot Matrix

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot

I need to build a correlation matrix and I am trying to configure some parameters to adapt the graph.  I am using the `corrplot` package.

I built a `corrplot` matrix this way:

```
corrplot(cor(d1[,2:14], d1[,2:14]), method=c("color"), bg = "white",
         addgrid.col = "gray50", tl.cex=1, type="lower",
         tl.col = "black",
         col = colorRampPalette(c("red","white","blue"))(100))
```

I need to show the correlation values in the lower matrix inside the color matrix that I built. How I can accomplish this?

The diagonal of the correlation matrix is always 1, and so I would like to know if it is possible to exclude the main diagonal from the lower matrix?

I would also like to show the significant correlation values using stars instead of squares. For example, (`*`, `**`, `***`).

Is it possible?